# Node.js + Lazy: Iterate file lines

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to lazy read a file, however I can't use `each()`.
I want to read the first line of a file, then the first of another file, and so on.

I'm trying to use the Iterator, but with no success.
This is my code:

```
var Lazy = require('lazy.js');

var it = Lazy.readFile("log.txt")
        .lines()
        .getIterator();

while(it.moveNext()){
    console.log(it.current());
}
```

`Lazy.readFile("log.txt").lines().size()` returns 0.

However, this works fine:

```
Lazy.readFile("log.txt")
        .lines()
        .each(function(line){
            console.log(line);
        });
```

Comment: is 'log.txt' in the current working directory? Try another name (e.g. 'not_exist.txt') - same result? Is the file growing while you read it (like `tail -F log.txt`)?

Comment: yes, the problem is not the file, because I can use `Lazy.readFile("log.txt").lines().each()`. I've updated my answer with more details.

Comment: Consider using `.takeWhile`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a part of Lazy.js that I admittedly haven't done a great job of explaining. Let me copy a snippet from [the current documentation for the `getIterator` method](http://danieltao.com/lazy.js/docs/#Sequence-getIterator) here:

> This method is used when asynchronously iterating over sequences. Any
>   type inheriting from Sequence must implement this method or it can't
>   support asynchronous iteration.
>
> Note that **this method is not intended to be used directly by
>   application code**. Rather, it is intended as a means for implementors
>   to potentially define custom sequence types that support either
>   synchronous or asynchronous iteration.

The issue you've run into here is that `Lazy.readFile` returns an *asynchronous* sequence. So `getIterator` will not work, because the `Iterator` type only exposes a synchronous interface.

I've actually updated Lazy.js since you posted this question; as of 0.3.2, calling `getIterator` on an async sequence [will throw an exception](http://danieltao.com/lazy.js/docs/#AsyncSequence-getIterator).

Comment: Than you for you answer.
I needed to use `getIterator` because I didn't want to read all the lines of a file. I needed to read the first line of `n` different files and process the one with the smallest timestamp until there was no lines to read from any file. For that specific scenario I needed to use `getIterator`.